# How do you convert quaternion/accelerometer data to opengl usable data

Tags: android, opengl-es, sensor-fusion

I have some data from a sensor device, i.e., accelerometer x,y,z and a quaternion. Using this information i would like to render a "line image" in an Android OpenGL View. Can someone help me about the part on how to convert acceleration values to something that can be used by OpenGL glTranslatef and glRotatef function's.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using the deprecate gltranslate or glrotate. instead just manage the correct transformation matrices directly.

converting a quaternion to matrix can be done with the following: [(sourced from my previous code)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/70991/32061)

```
float[] quatToMat(quaternion q, float* result)
{
    //based on algorithm on wikipedia
    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Quaternion
    float w = q.scalar ();
    float x = q.x();
    float y = q.y();
    float z = q.z();

    float n =  x*x + y*y + z*z + w*w;
    float s =  n == 0?  0 : 2 / n;
    float wx = s * w * x, wy = s * w * y, wz = s * w * z;
    float xx = s * x * x, xy = s * x * y, xz = s * x * z;
    float yy = s * y * y, yz = s * y * z, zz = s * z * z;

    return new float[]{ 1 - (yy + zz),         xy + wz ,         xz - wy ,0,
                             xy - wz ,    1 - (xx + zz),         yz + wx ,0,
                             xz + wy ,         yz - wx ,    1 - (xx + yy),0,
                             0 ,               0 ,               0 ,1  };
}
```

If you still want to use the fixed function pipeline then push that into glMultMatrix.

Comment: gl.glTranslatef(q.X, q.Y, q.Z);
    rv = computeRotationVectorFromQ(q)
    gl.glRotatef(rv.a, rv.x, rv.y, rv.z);

Currently this is how i use the data.  If i follow your suggestion what OpenGL function should i use to apply the transformation. Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: multMatrix will have the same result as first getting the angle-axis from the quaternion just more efficiently. I hate it when people talk quaternions and will still grab back to the angle-axis at the first hurdle.

Comment: @Soundararajan: The fixed-function transformations such as `glTranslatef`, `glRotatef`, etc. are gone in modern GL (3.0+) and GL ES (2.0+). If you convert this to an arbitrary matrix you can pass it directly to a shader (required for ES 2.0) or call `glMultMatrixf (...)` on it if you are using ES 1.x. You mentioned Android, so I suspect you're either on ES 1.x or 2.0+.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman, Thanks . I use ES 2.0. I will try your suggestion . :-)